# Rails render ajax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I've a index.html.erb like that

```
<div id="carte_items">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="category_14" class="category-group">
      <p class="category">Pizzas tradicionais</p>

      <ul class="tags">
        <li>
          <div class="links" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">
              <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            </a>

            <a href="#" data-remote="true">
              <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          Pizza X
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="links" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">
              <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            </a>

            <a href="#" data-remote="true">
              <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          Pizza X
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, I've that in my products.js.coffee

```
$("ul.tags li").on('mouseover', () ->
 $(this).find('.links').show()
).on('mouseout', () ->
 $(this).find('.links').hide()
)
```

When I access for the first time my index.html.erb everything works fine. But for the links still working like in my first access, I have to copy the source in products.js.coffee to the index.js.erb bellow. Like when I use my search, that use ajax for to do the search, if I not copy the source like bellow, the ".links" does not show anymore.

Them I've the index.js.erb like that

```
$("#carte_items").html("<%= j(render 'carte_items') %>");
$("ul.tags li").on('mouseover', function() {
  return $(this).find('.links').show();
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  return $(this).find('.links').hide();
});
```

Why a have to copy the source? It does not have to work fine just with the source in the file products.js.coffee without copy to index.js.erb??

Thanks for help.

Comment: try using the `live` function to bind the elements with the event handler functions ... look at http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Hi, in the version 1.9 of jquery "live" was removed. This was depreciated on the verison 1.7 like you can see in your link that you post me. But thanks. Any more help send me again

Comment: Did you try `delegate` instead of `on`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("ul.tags").delegate('li', 'mouseover', () ->
 $(this).find('.links').show()
).delegate('li', 'mouseout', () ->
 $(this).find('.links').hide()
)
```

or:

```
$("ul.tags").on('mouseover', 'li', () ->
 $(this).find('.links').show()
).on('mouseout', 'li', () ->
 $(this).find('.links').hide()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery API docs:

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

*Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.*

[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

*Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.*

Delegate: "... now or **in the future**". So try `delegate()` instead of `on()`.

Hope it works!